# Compatibility tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The wording of the Compatibility tag seems to be describing the compatibility of servers and CMS's.  I could not find a tag that seems to be defined for compatibility of extensions to CiviCRM version.  Am I misreading this?  Should there be a new tag?

(Incidently, there are five different forms of "tag" here.)

Comment: What type of issue you'd like to flag specifically? I'm not sure I understand how you would want to use that tag